# private final int blanki; private final int blankj;

Tags: java, variables, private, final

I have this code:

```
public final class Board {

    private final int[][] blocks;
    private final int N;
    private final int blanki;
    private final int blankj;
    int i, j;

    // construct a board from an N-by-N array of blocks
   public Board(int[][] blocks)  {

        this.blocks = new int[blocks.length][blocks.length];

        for(i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < blocks.length; j++){
                this.blocks[i][j] = blocks[i][j];
                if(blocks[i][j] == 0) {
                    int f = i;
                    int c = j;
                }
            }
        }
        this.N = this.dimension();
        this.blanki = f;
        this.blankj = c;
    }

}
```

and get following errors:

File: C:\Users\cbozanic\algs4\Board.java  [line: 28]
Error: f cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\cbozanic\algs4\Board.java  [line: 29]
Error: c cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\cbozanic\algs4\Board.java  [line: 159]
Error: The local variable s may not have been initialized

I do not really get what is tat I am doing wrong! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is because you have declared `f` and `c` as variables inside a loop.
Also I strongly advice you to use so advanced IDE - it will hep you get rid of such mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

`f` and `c` are defined in the scope of the `for` loop. They are not visible outside of it :

```
this.blocks = new int[blocks.length][blocks.length];

for(i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < blocks.length; j++){
            int f = i;
            int c = j;
    } //From this point, f and c are not defined anymore
}
}
this.N = this.dimension();
this.blanki = f; //Here, f does not exist
this.blankj = c; //Here, c does not exist
```

If you want to work with f and c, declare them before the loop :

```
int f = ...
int c = ...

 for(i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < blocks.length; j++){
            f = ...;
            c = ...;
    }
}
```

For the message `The local variable s may not have been initialized`, it means that you declared and used the variable without initializing it. For example :

```
int s; //For example, int s = 0; would make sense.
s++;
```

**Note** : class attributes take a default value when a new instance is created but local variables stay in a "not initialized" state.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `f` is not visible in this scope:

```
this.blanki = f;
```

Consider adding `int f = 0;` in the beginning of the method.

Same applies to variable `c`.